# sqlldr control file fileds with variable

Tags: database, oracle, sql-loader

```
infile ‘c:sandeep.txt’
truncate
into table emp
fields TERMINATED BY “|”
trailing nullcols(
column_name constant “${variable}”,
)
```

sqlldr run by shell script, have any method pass variable to sqlldr and make fields use what I passed to it ?

Comment: add some infomation: column_name  which need variable , this field not contained in data file, variable is generate by data file name.thks

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use OS environment variables in the control file; not least because it would have to support many versions. You could generate the control file from a template, substituting in your value, as part fo the script. Not sure the best way to do that in Windows though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#-- setup
col_name=MY_COL_NAME
#-- create the control file.  Have to escape the double-quotes
rm myloader.ctl      2>/dev/null
echo infile ‘c:sandeep.txt’                >> myloader.ctl
echo truncate                              >> myloader.ctl
echo into table emp                        >> myloader.ctl
echo fields TERMINATED BY \"\|\"            >> myloader.ctl
echo "trailing nullcols("                  >> myloader.ctl
echo column_name constant \"${col_name}\", >> myloader.ctl
echo ")"                                   >> myloader.ctl
#
#-- check the results
cat myloader.ctl
#-- run sqlldr
sqlldr control=myloader.ctl
```